# Angular 2 - Multiple HTTP get request and cache response

Tags: angular, angular-http

I have to make three HTTP request in angular 2 and need to cache the response object on the application.

Any clue on the below implementation:

```
this._Data = this.http.get('http://www.example.com/one')
.map((res: Response) => res.json())
.flatMap((one: any) => {
    return Observable.forkJoin(
        Observable.of(one),
        this.http.get('http://www.example.com/two').map((res: Response) => res.json()),
        this.http.get('http://www.example.com/three').map((res: Response) => res.json()),
    )
    .do((data: any[]) => {
        const one = data[0];
        const two = data[1];
        const three = data[2];
        return one;
    });
});
console.log(this._Data);
return this._Data;
```

I didn't receive a proper response. Appreciate for any clue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this :

```
this.http.get('http://www.example.com/one')
    .flatMap((one: Response) => {
        console.log('one Response', one);
        return this.http.get('http://www.example.com/two')
    })
    .flatMap((two: Response) => {
        console.log('two Response', two);
        return this.http.get('http://www.example.com/three')        
    })
    .subscribe((three: Response) => {
        console.log('three Response', three);
    })
```

If you want speed up response use `Observable.forkJoin`

```
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.http.get('http://www.example.com/one'),
    this.http.get('http://www.example.com/two'),
    this.http.get('http://www.example.com/three')
).subscribe((responses) => {
    // responses[0] -> response of one
    // responses[1] -> response of two
    // responses[2] -> response of three
})
```

Comment: Thanks of your clue...Is that cache the response as well.

Comment: the clue is that a Observable NOT run until you subscribe